# SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) web portal not working with Azure Application Gateway v2

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

Has anyone had luck getting SSRS to work when behind a v2 Azure Application Gateway? The site loads, but randomly prompts for authentication and fails to render part of the site properly.

I first tried this with SSRS 2016 back in 2019 and worked with Azure support for months with no satisfying end result. They had me changing authentication settings and running traces all over the place. I eventually gave up because we were already using a v1 which worked 100% fine.

I tried this again today with an SSRS 2017 server and run in to the same exact issue. I was sure MS had fixed/tweaked something but unfortunately I was wrong :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using the default authentication which is NTLM. As of now (Feb 25th 2022) Application Gateway v2 doesn't support NTLM. SKU v1 support it but v2 doesn't!

[Does Application Gateway V2 support proxying requests with NTLM authentication?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#does-application-gateway-v2-support-proxying-requests-with-ntlm-authentication)

Comment: Well that's.. interesting. I wonder why MS support spent three months working with me and didn't point that out? I'll have to see if I can get SSRS switched over to using Kerberos. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Another option is to use load balancer instead of app gateway. That is what I switched too for SSRS. For other apps, app gateway continues to work.

Comment: Hey @amit_g, I actually just took some time and verified with packet captures that negotiation is happening with Kerberos, authentication headers start with YII. Any additional thoughts on what the issue could be related to?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to use Azure app gw v2 with SSRS by creating a basic iis site with no auth for the health probe (https://sub.mydomain.com/healthprobe.html). Once the health probe is happy I can browse via the WAF to https://sub.mydomain.com/reports & https://sub.mydomain.com/reportserver

Comment: I will have to give this a shot! Out of curiosity, what version of SSRS are you running?

Comment: Actually, I just re-read that. Were you having issues with the default health probe because the SSRS site prompts for authentication? I work around that by setting the HTTP response status code match to 200-401